# Expand height of child div to the height of its parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

My webpages is structured as such:

[image]

And it looks like this:

[image]

My `link__wrapper` CSS is the following:

```css
.link__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

My `link__infoContainer` is **not** expanding to 100% of the `link__wrapper` height. See here:

[image]

Here is my `link__infoContainer` code:

```css
.link__infoContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  position: inherit;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

How can I make my `link__infoContainer` match the height of my `link__wrapper`?

Comment: the code in the screenshot is very bad practice for SO.

Comment: delete `align-items: center` from `.link__wrapper`. because the `link__info Container` has a height in `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `.link__wrapper` class to this:

```css
.link__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch; /* "stretch" instead of "center" */
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

This will stretch `.link__wrapper`'s children to its height.

Comment: Worked liked a charm. Thanks my guy

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure

html{ box-sizing: border-box;}

second, check the code to see that div.link_wrapper is not inheriting a margin. if so set the margin to 0%